# Pyspark Dataframe unable to read real datatype data correctly from SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark

I am reading data in Spark DataFrame using below code but getting unexpected result.

Source SQLSERVER Table

[image]

Code used to read data from SQLServer

```
jdbcDF = spark.read \
.format("jdbc") \
.option("url", url) \
.option("dbtable", "schema.tablename") \
.option("user", "user") \
.option("password", "password") \
.load()
```

Output from above code

[image]

I am expecting below output.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share what is the schema in your input `jdbc` database? Normally, if this is `int`, `float` or other, this should be automatically inferred.

Comment: Are you looking result in excel?

Comment: @napoleon_borntoparty it's real  in database.

Comment: @Ajay_SK I am looking result on spark shell, excel is just for reference.

Comment: I think it's an error in conversion from `REAL` in SQL SERVER to Scala `FloatType` - saving it as string. I'll build a docker container and test it out and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** - This is expected due to loss of precision beyond 4 bytes of data on `REAL` type - `REAL` is an approximate numeric type - Spark then takes that imprecise value and interprets it as `DoubleType`. If you wish to have exact matches, you should look at exact-precision types in your underlying databse, such as `DECIMAL` which should have up to 17 storage bytes (default precision of 38), which will get picked up as `DecimalType` in Spark (see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-data-type-differences?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Longer read on how I tested this**

I reconstructed your problem using MSSQL and Spark on Docker and can confirm that this appears to be the expected behaviour.
Reviewing the documentation on `REAL` type, this stands out in particular:

> Real data can hold a value 4 bytes in size, meaning it has 7 digits of precision  (the number of digits to the right of the decimal point). It's also a floating-point numeric that is identical to the floating point statement float(24).

This in essence means that your change of precision from `5.987691E+07` to `5.9876908E7` is expected (E notation is just showing differently on `Spark` and `MSSQL`). How the rest of the value beyond 7 digit precision is populated is not particularly deterministic - for example, while you got `5.987691E+07` interpreted as `5.9876908E7`, my code gave me `5.9876912E7` (as you can see below) - this is due to loss of precision in `REAL` type after all 4 bytes of data are exhausted.

Now to retrace my steps (Docker steps are optional if you have MSSQL/Spark on host machine):

1. `docker-compose up` 2 containers, one with `PySpark`, one with `MSSQL`, expose all necessary ports (1433 for MSSQL, 8888 for Notebook on Spark side, etc.)
2. On host machine, run `mssql -u sa -p <password>` to get into your MSSQL instance.
3. Run the following commands:

```sql
mssql> create database test_db;
mssql> create table dbo.test_table (name varchar(100), value real);
mssql> insert into dbo.test_table values ('val1', 5.987691E+07);
mssql> insert into dbo.test_table values ('val2', 5.987691E+07);
mssql> insert into dbo.test_table values ('val3', 1.23456789E+07);

mssql> select * from dbo.test_table;
name  value   
----  --------
val1  59876912
val2  59876912
val3  12345679
```

4. Spark side, create relevant `SparkSession` with all jars (MSSQL JDBC driver can be found here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774).

```
spark = (
  SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("MSSQL Connection")
  .master("local[*]")
  .config("spark.jars", "/etc/sqljdbc42.jar")  # required to connect to MSSQL via JDBC
  .getOrCreate()
)
```

5. Read the table as DataFrame from JDBC source

```
df = spark.read \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("driver" , "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://mssql:1433") \
  .option("dbtable", "dbo.test_table") \
  .option("user", "sa") \
  .option("password", "<password>") \
  .load()
```

6. Investigate `df`.

```
df.show()
+----+-----------+
|name|      value|
+----+-----------+
|val1|5.9876912E7|
|val2|5.9876912E7|
|val3|1.2345679E7|
+----+-----------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: double (nullable = true)
```

In order to get exact values to match, I believe you need to change the type in your underlying MSSQL database to something with higher precision, for example `DECIMAL`.

Comment: I also think it's one SQLSERVER Side, actually it's a different team who generates this data. I probably need to work with them. thanks

Comment: @AdityaSahu Happy to help - if this answers your question, please accept and upvote. Cheers!